# What happens when straight is on board

Tags: rules

Suppose 3 people are playing.
1st has A , K
2nd has K , Q
3rd has 5 , A
And cards on board are 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10
Who will win please tell ?

Comment: Best 5-card hand wins. In this case, all three players have 6-7-8-9-10, so they split. If one of them had a J, or even better, J-Q, he'd have a higher straight.

Comment: If a player had a flush they win but you don't provide that information.

Answer (score 1):

This is a split pot, all players have the same best 5-card hand (straight to 10).